# Picking up value of __attribute__ ((constructor)) function in main

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to create a before-main evaluation like this:

```
int evaluate(int argc, char** argv) __attribute__ ((constructor));
int evaluate(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int result = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (result == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(?????)
{
    if (????? == 0)
        printf("Wrong number.");
    else
        printf("It is 1!");
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I am doing this purely to get myself more familiar with C, passing command line arguments and using pre-main functions.

Comment: What is wrong with `int main(int argc, char** argv) { evaulate(argc, argv); }` ? If you are learning C, don't learn compiler specific syntaxes. Ok. Then I don't understand your question. What do you want to pick value of? What does ????? represent? You want to modify the value and type of arguments of `main` function?

Comment: Nothing. But that is not what I am trying to do, as I stated in a comment.

Comment: a function annotated with `__attribute__ ((constructor))` should return `void`

Comment: The *only* way you get a handle on `argc` and `argv` will be via `main()`, so even if you can sort out the `constructor` stuff, you won't get to the parameters.  I also concur with @KamilCuk that there's little value in this while learning C, though I appreciate diving into what's clearly an advanced topic.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I've already tried this behaviour. When I create a function with __attribute__ ((constructor)) with arguments int argc, char** argv, I can use these values without any problem in function before main.

Answer (score 0):

This is very platform-dependent. The glibc dynamic loader passes the `argc`, `argv`, and `envp` to ELF constructors, so you can access the program arguments in this way. To my knowledge, this is an undocumented dynamic loader feature, so you probably should not rely on this behavior.

For the result of the check, you will have to write it to a global variable (or record it in some other global data structure). The implementation discards the